# How do I know how many partitions a DynamoDB table is spread over?

Tags: database, load-balancing, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon's DynamoDB in designed for guaranteed performances. A customer must provision throughput for each of it's tables.

To achieve this performances, tables are transparently spread over multiple "servers" AKA "partitions".

Amazon provides us with a ["best practice" guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html) for dimensioning and optimizing the throughput. In this guide, we are told that the **provisioned throughput is evenly divided over the partitions**. In other words, If the requests are not evenly distributed over the partitions, only a *fraction* of the reserved (and paid) throughput will be available to the application.

In the **worst case scenario**, it will be:

```
worst_throughput = provisioned_and_paid_throughput / partitions
```

To estimate this "worst_throughput", I need to know the total number of partitions. Where can I find it or how do I estimate it ?

Comment: The post is misleading. The throughput per partition is NOT evenly divided: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions.Throughput

Comment: @ed9er AWS document you reference is saying `Provisioned I/O capacity for the table is divided evenly among these physical partitions.`. I think throughput per partition is evenly divided.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://dzone.com/articles/partitioning-behavior-of-dynamodb) could help you.

Comment: Btw while many think of partitions as servers, I'd bet that DynamoDB has many partitions per server. Ref: "Designing Data-Intensive Applications"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says, "When storing data, Amazon DynamoDB divides a table's items into multiple partitions, and distributes the data primarily based on the hash key element."

What you really want to know is the throughput of a single partition.  It seems like you can test that by hammering a single key.

Comment: At the moment, I select a random item and load test it. From the results I can infer the actual partition count. I was wondering if there were better methods than "brute force". It appears that not.

Comment: See the comment on the question, this is not accurate once partitions start overflowing and automatically splitting!

Comment: @Philip Does partition merge in a some way as they split? In other words assuming that number of data I store in DynamoDB table is decreasing (let's say cache eviction is happening), will the number of partition decrease and as a result my write/read throughput per partition recover?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue it's been a while since I read the documentation, but if I recall they do not merge again once split. It might take a while to find it, but you can find the answer in the docs.

Comment: Once a partition size exceeds 10GB, it can automatically split. In that case, this formula will be unreliable. If you want, you can open a support case and directly ask AWS support for the accurate number of partitions.

Answer (score 2):

See this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions

Which has some simple calculations you can carry out based on the amount of read and write capacity you provision.  *Note that this is only for initial capacity.*  As your usage of dynamodb continues, these calculations will have less and less relevance.

`A single partition can hold approximately 10 GB of data, and can support a maximum of 3,000 read capacity units or 1,000 write capacity units.`

Comment: This will only give you the partitions if it was the initial capacity for the table. If you started with low number and increased the capacity in past, dynamodb double the partitions if it cannot accommodate the new capacity in current number of partitions. If a partition gets full it splits in into two. I don't see any easy way of finding how many partitions my table currently has. (source in the same link as the answer)

Comment: @Ajak6 you are correct, what I quote is just the initial allocation.  The link also talks about tracking your data usage through time, but it doesn't seem straightforward to do so.  I will update the answer.